# Ionic local CORS error, yet headers are set

Tags: .htaccess, cors

I am developing a Ionic app locally (on my machine) that uses XHR requests. Why do I get CORS errors?

Error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://id:pwd@mydomain.com/app/proDB.jsonp' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here the .htaccess on my server (located in /home/gwwdpcf/www/app/.htaccess) :

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "L pit blod"
AuthUserFile /home/gwwdpcf/www/app/.htpasswd
require valid-user

#   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
#   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# Enable cross domain access control
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true


# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```

Client-side code:

```js
const url = dbUrl() {  
    return decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent("http://example.org/app/proDB.jsonp"))    
  }

  const username = 'id';
  const password = 'pwd';
  const credentials = username + ':' + password;
  const base64Credentials = btoa(credentials);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);  
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Credentials);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');  // Assuming you're expecting XML data

  if (url === "proDB.jsonp") {
    console.log("--Asking local proDB.json...");
  } else {
    console.log("--Sending XMLHttpRequest...");
  }

  request.timeout = XHRtimeout;
  request.ontimeout = function () {    
    reject({
      status: this.status,
      statusText: request.statusText,
    });
  };
  request.onload = async function () {
    if (
      request.readyState === 4 &&
      ((request.status >= 200 && request.status <= 299) ||
        request.status === 304 ||
        request.status === 0)
    ) {   
 ...
```

Edit: here's what I inspect in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Is authentication taking place _before_ or _after_ CORS?

Comment: I don't how to respond, at the same time ? I added the client-side code. Let me know how to clarify more.

Comment: Also should I use 'https' instead of 'http' in my url ?

Comment: On the basis of the client code you added, I can tell you that your request will be preceded by a preflight request. And if authentication occurs before CORS on the server side, preflight will fail, because [preflight requests do not carry credentials](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I partially understand. Can you tell me what code (client and headers) would be best practice in my case?

Comment: The question is not so much about good or bad practice, although I would discourage you from configuring CORS in Apache config; doing so is just too error-prone and config changes are unlikely to get properly reviewed. The question is whether the requested resource configured for CORS in a way that's permissive enough (but no more) to allow network access to your client. In my experience, most CORS failures stem from a request header that happens to be disallowed by the CORS configuration.

Comment: In your browser's Network tab, inspect the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header of the preflight request. For things to work, all the values listed there must also be listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.